# Why can't labels prints integrers?

Tags: c++-cli

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    int result = 0;
    result += 1;
    label1->Text = result;
}
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this code?

Comment: Forgot to mention that the error I got was `E1767`

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: `System::Object^ sender` I have never seen parameters passed like this.

Comment: @foragerDev `function "System::Windows::Forms::Text::set" cannot be called with given argument list

Comment: Provide more details in the question.

Comment: @foragerDev It's [C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI), the `^` denotes a "managed object" or something like that.

Comment: @dragon What happens if you did `label1->Text = "1";`?  Does that work?  If so, then the issue is converting the integer to a string.

Comment: I want so if the button is clicked the int value grows with 1 and that int value is label's text

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie can you provide a tutorial on converting?

Comment: @dragon First, did the sample work?  If so, C++ has `std::to_string()` to convert to a `std::string`.  I do not know what facilities C++/CLI has in converting numeric data to strings.

Comment: Yes, the sample does work but I don't want the value to be just 1. I want it to change when the button is clicked and the label's text is equal to the int value. Also I didn't know that that this was CLI, hope you can understand.

Answer (score -1):

```
value += 1;
String^ lol = System::Convert::ToString(value); 
label1->Text = lol;
```